# How can I get a list of all classes and methods used in a Visual Studio project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Are there any reporting tools for Visual Studio 2008 that can build a list of all classes and methods used in a project?

Comment: Without having it in compiled form?

Answer (score 5):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) can create such [reports](http://www.ndepend.com/SampleReports/OnNUnit/NDependReport.html). It has its own query language, so that even you can select types/members depending on some metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection if you need all the names, something like (in VB.NET)

```
 Dim myType As Type = GetType(myclassname)
 Dim myArrayMethodInfo As MethodInfo() = myType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
    For i As Integer = 0 To myArrayMethodInfo.Length - 1
        Dim mi As MethodInfo = CType(myArrayMethodInfo(i), MethodInfo)            
        Debug.Print(mi.Name)                       
    Next i
```

Or you can use a 3rd party tool such as [OxyProject Metrics](http://www.techinceptions.com/CodeMetrics.html) if you just want to count them.

Comment: I am working such a script to write a list of method names used in my solution. Could you pls tell me what is this myclassname. I have a ton of classes in my code. cant pass each and every classname.